# Can't execute any commands in bash except as sudo

Tags: command-line, bash

I don't know what I did but suddenly i can't use any commands except and only preceded with sudo. No matter the command I get  bash: /home/otis/bin/ls: cannot execute binary file. Even cp I get bash: /home/otis/bin/cp: cannot execute binary file. if I put sudo before all is well. How do I correct this so every single command does not have to be done as superuser.

Comment: What do you see in the `rwx` bits if you `ls -l` these binaries?

Comment: Unless you have a good reason for having system binaries in your home directory, it looks like you messed up your PATH. It should look something like `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games`

Comment: So many questions to ask.  (1) Have you tried logging out and logging in again?  (2) Do you really have files in your ***private*** `bin` directory (`/home/otis/bin`) with the names `ls`, `cp`, etc…?  (2½) Why?  (2⅔) What are they?  (3) Do shell built-in commands like `cd`, `echo`, and `set` still work?  (4) What is your `PATH` environment variable set to?  (Either type `echo $PATH` or type `set` and look for a line beginning `PATH=`.)  (4½) Why?

Comment: Otis, just to re-iterate what has been said, if you *haven't* created a `bin` folder in your home directory and populated it with these binaries, and modified your path, then something has gone seriously wrong.  One of the possibilities is that your system has been compromised.  If you *haven't* done these things yourself, then stop trying to fix things and let us help investigate - you may be trying to run binaries that were put there maliciously.

Comment: Yes I have logged in and out. Yes there is a /home otis/bin directory with those files.. don't know how or why. No built in commands only work as sudo. My path looks like this: bash: /home/otis/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/bin: No such file or directory

Comment: I didn't put them there and I am the only one that uses this computer. How could this have happened and what should i do to secure it now. Do I wipe it out and start all over.

Comment: Wow.  If `cd`, `echo`, and `set` don’t work, you may need to throw away your computer and buy a new one.  :-)

Comment: Who owns the binaries in your bin directory? Show us the output of `ls -l /home/otis/bin`

Comment: I own everything. The user is me and so is the group.

Comment: Can you try `sudo mv /home/otis/bin /home/otis/bin.old`.  This will rename the directory, which will then allow the proper binaries in /bin to execute.

Answer (score 2):

There's something wrong in your path. It works with sudo because it uses root settings.

Did you modify your $PATH environment variable?

In a terminal type `$PATH`. You should get something like: `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`

I guess that yours would /usr/local/sbin:**/home/otis/bin**:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin or something like that.

To solve this issue try typing: `PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Okay with $PATH this is what I got bash: /home/otis/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/bin: No such file or directory

Comment: You can fix this temporarily by following the instructions above, but you need to figure out why this is happening. I would look in .bashrc and .bash_profile first.

Comment: @ToDo: I believe you meant “In a terminal type `echo $PATH`.”